# CVS: update a file with its ancestors but without their brethren

Tags: cvs

I have a file in CVS under `x/y/f.txt`.  In my local copy, I have `x/`, but no `x/y/` and I want to fetch `f.txt` from the repo.  Is there any combination of CVS command-line switches which can make it pull only `x/y/f.txt` with all of its ancestors (in this case `x/y/`) but without any collateral files (such as `x/y/g.txt` or `x/z`)?

---

The only way I've found so far is:

```
cvs up -d -l x/y
# ... but be careful not to pass -P (``prune'') implicitly via your ~/.cvsrc
# ``-l'' means act locally, i.e. no recursion
# Do the above for every missing ancestor directory, in left-to-right order
# And ultimately:
cvs up x/y/f.txt
```

However, it would be rather inelegant for a shell script to split a path and iterate through the ancestors, so I'm still looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a working copy checked out or is this for a fresh checkout?

If you already have a working copy `cvs up -d x/y/f.txt` should do the job.

The `-d` should only be necessary if the `x` and `y` folders do not already exist. If they do exist, you can also just `cd` into the `x/y` folder and do `cvs up f.txt`.

If this should be a fresh checkout then `cvs co -N x/y/f.txt` is probably what you need.

Comment: I have a partial working copy---x but not x/y.
"cvs up -d x/y/f.txt" complains that x/y is missing.
"cvs co -N x/y/f.txt" says "cannot expand modules".